# Filtering hierarchically ordered comma separated text in a row in R

Tags: r, database, filter

Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame ("user.id" = c("usr1", "usr2", "usr3", "usr4"),
                  "gender" = c("m", "f", "m", "f"),
                  "fav.car.rank" = c("toyota, subaru, honda", "honda, subaru, toyota", "toyota, honda, subaru", "subaru, toyota, honda"))
```

I have a column called “fav.car.rank”. The car brands are comma separated and in an hierarchical order (from most fav to least fav. // e.g. usr1’s most fav. brand is toyota).

I want to create separate columns for each car brand which includes the ranking of that car brand. I want a data frame that looks like this:

| user.id | gender | toyota | subaru | honda |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| usr1 | m | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| usr2 | f | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| usr3 | m | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| usr4 | f | 2 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is to split at the `,` to expand the rows with `separate_rows`, create the sequence column by `rev`ersed after grouping by 'user.id' and then reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 separate_rows(fav.car.rank) %>% 
 group_by(user.id) %>%
 mutate(n = rev(row_number())) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = fav.car.rank, values_from = n)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  user.id gender toyota subaru honda
  <chr>   <chr>   <int>  <int> <int>
1 usr1    m           3      2     1
2 usr2    f           1      2     3
3 usr3    m           3      1     2
4 usr4    f           2      3     1
```